# applications to calculus questions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

A farmer has 80m length of fencing. He wants to use it to form 3 sides of a rectangular enclosure against an existing fence, which provides the 4th side. find the maximum area that he can enclose and give its dimensions. I know I have to use the principle of stationary points but I don't know how to begin the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two side lengths be $l,w$.

Then, $2 l + w = 80$ and you want to maximize $A=lw = l ( 80 - 2l)$.

Solve $\frac{dA}{dl}=0$ for $l$, see that $\frac{dA}{dl}$ changes sign so that this value of $l$ is a maximizer then plug it into the expression for $A$ to find the maximized area.

Alternatively, note that $A$ specifies a parabola and look for its vertex as the maximizer since it opens downwards.

Answer (score 0):

*I know I have to use the principle of stationary points but I don't know how to begin the problem.*

The guidelines below (from [Larson’s book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xn9rXyPSrzAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ron+larson+calculus+book&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7pLivxOXJAhWHh5AKHYNAAVEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=ron%20larson%20calculus%20book&f=false)) show you how to start (this and related problems).

1. ***Identify all given quantities and all quantities to be determined. If possible, make a sketch and label it with any relevant measurements.***

Here is the rectangular enclosure:

[image]

Given quantity: the length of fencing which is $80$

Quantities to be determined: The area $A$ of the rectangular enclosure and the dimensions $x$ and $y$.

2. ***Write a primary equation for the quantity that is to be maximized or
   minimized.***

The quantity that is to be maximized is the area $A$. So, a primary equation is
$$A=xy$$

3. ***Reduce the primary equation to one having a single independent variable.
   This may involve the use of secondary equations relating the independent
   variables of the primary equation.***

From the step 1 we get the secondary equation $2x+y=80$ which implies
$$y=80-2x$$
Substituting this in the equation of step 2 we get
$$A(x)=x(80-2x)$$
$$A(x)=-2x^2+80x$$

4. ***Determine the feasible domain of the primary equation. That is, determine
   the values for which the stated problem makes sense.***

$$0<x<40,\qquad 0<y<80$$

5. ***Determine the desired maximum or minimum value by the calculus
   techniques.***

Now, we have to do the calculation. The first thing is to solve $A'(x)=0$ with respect the domain specified in the step 4.